# jQuery UI smooth transition on drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the jQuery UI card drop plugin to create a very simple match up game. I want to make the snapping transition of the card dropping a bit smoother so that when you drop the correct card over the correct slot it moves into place steadily.

Her's a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AyN2a/

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
// Create the slots
var words = [ '<img src="images/image1.png" width="200px" height="200px" alt="">', '<img src="images/image2.png" width="200px" height="200px" alt="">', '<img src="images/image3.png" width="200px" height="200px" alt="">', '<img src="images/image4.png" width="200px" height="200px" alt="">', '<img src="images/image5.png" width="200px" height="200px" alt="">', '<img src="images/image6.png" width="200px" height="200px" alt="">', '<img src="images/image7.png" width="200px" height="200px" alt="">'];
for ( var i=1; i<=7; i++ ) {
  $('<div>' + words[i-1] + '</div>').data( 'number', i ).appendTo( '#cardSlots' ).droppable( {
    accept: '#cardPile div',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleCardDrop
  } );
} 

function handleCardDrop( event, ui ) {
  var slotNumber = $(this).data( 'number' );
  var cardNumber = ui.draggable.data( 'number' );

  if ( slotNumber == cardNumber ) {
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
    $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
    correctCards++;
  } 

  if ( correctCards == 7 ) {
    $('#successMessage').show();
    $('#successMessage').animate( {
      left: '380px',
      width: '150px',
      height: '150px',
      opacity: 1
    } );
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward Yea sure, thanks. http://jsfiddle.net/AyN2a/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `using` option of jQuery UI [position](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/), it allows you to set an animation on position applying.

Ref:

> Type: Function() When specified, the actual property setting is
>   delegated to this callback. Receives two parameters: The first is a
>   hash of top and left values for the position that should be set and
>   can be forwarded to .css() or .animate(). The second provides feedback
>   about the position and dimensions of both elements, as well as
>   calculations to their relative position. Both target and element have
>   these properties: element, left, top, width, height. In addition,
>   there's horizontal, vertical and important, giving you twelve
>   potential directions like { horizontal: "center", vertical: "left",
>   important: "horizontal" }.

Like:

```
ui.draggable.position({
    of: $(this),
    my: 'left top',
    at: 'left top',
    using: function (css, calc) {
        $(this).animate(css, 200, 'linear');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g6NZ9/1/